# Datatable compute c# filter string

Tags: c#, group-by

I have a problem with this code:

```
_dtReturn.Rows[i][_calculatedField.OutPutColumnName] = 
    _dtSource.Compute(_calculatedField.enmFunction.ToString() + 
    "(" + _calculatedField.ColumnName + ")", _filterString);
```

The string generate it is the seguent:

```
_dtReturn.Rows[i][_calculatedField.OutPutColumnName] = 
    _dtSource.Compute("Sum(Affidate)","lottoimportazione = 44438 AND Regione = 'SICILIA'");
```

The code generate this exception :

From Google Translate: "An unhandled exception of type ' System.Data.DataException ' in System.Data.dll

Additional information : Invalid use the Sum () function and the type of aggregation : Boolean ."

Eccezione non gestita di tipo 'System.Data.DataException' in System.Data.dll

Ulteriori informazioni: Utilizzo non valido della funzione Sum() e del tipo di aggregazione: Boolean.

CAN someone help me?

Comment: You need to translate the exception details to English.

Comment: What is the data type of `Affidate`? I do not think you can sum a boolean without casting it

Comment: The translation is: An unhandled exception of type  'System.Data.DataException' in System.Data.dll; Additional information : Invalid use the Sum () function and the type of aggregation : Boolean

Comment: It appears that Affidate is a bool value whereas the Sum() function most likely accepts a collection, list or range of numbers, integers, etc. Affidate from Italian translates to Entrust which seems to confirm Affidate is a bool or range of Boolean values. This could be your issue. Can you confirm this information?

Comment: You are right . The field was declared as Boolean and not come Integer  . A mistake in the design of the database